# Cannot import modules in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I cannot import any modules in Powershell due to this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> import-module failoverclusters
The term 'import-module' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or     script file. Verify the term and
 try again.
At line:1 char:14
+ import-module  <<<< failoverclusters
```

This was with a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I installed Powershell as a Windows feature through the Server Manager. It was not installed already when I installed Windows Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because Windows 2008 only comes with PowerShell 1.0 which used Snapins. If you need module support: install PowerShell 2.0 or 3.0. Links til installers:

Powershell 2.0: [x64 (64-bit)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20430) or [x86 (32-bit)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11829)

[PowerShell 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)

To install PS 3.0 you need at least 2008 SP2(and download the windows **6.0** 64 or 32 bit version).

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the PowerShell icon and choose the "Import system modules" option. Then run the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.